# Rails ajax request on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

How to automatically call ajax function on page load - Rails Ajax

For Example

consider the following ajax call.

```
<div id="result"><%= link_to item,blog_comments_path({:comment => "Hello", :user => "MrX"}), :remote => true %></div>
```

here i need to click the link to make the ajax request. Instead of that i need the call should happen automatically on page load

Comment: When you are already loading page, why you want to use ajax. You can run simple `function` on page load

Comment: Thank  you @Sontya  . However i have requirement to call the similar function after page loading to add comments automatically

Comment: Try: `$(document).ready(function() { $('#result').trigger('click') });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var clicked;
clicked = function() {
   $('#result').trigger('click');
};

$(document).ready(clicked);
$(document).on('page:load', clicked);
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#result').trigger('click') });
```

**EDIT**

You can use JQuery to make synchronous ajax calls
See the below example http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/EN8nc/6/

Try this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
It has different callbacks, like when all request completed call `success` callback

Comment: It is working. How to make more than one ajax resquests from the same page with out blocking one another.

Comment: Specify in clicked function, with the different ids like `$('#result1').trigger('click');` `$('#result2').trigger('click');`

Comment: @Thank You Sontya. The solution is working but second request called after finishing the first one. i need both should be called at the same time (Parallel)

Comment: Try this `$('#result1, #result2').trigger('click');`

Comment: @Sontya- still same behavior . second one is called after completion of the first one.

Comment: have you seen my updated answer, you can use `jquery` callbacks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){ 
  $('#result').trigger('click') 
});
```